# Time Warping Variable Initialization?

Tags: variables, initialization, raku

In the following simple for loop we create an array (@a) by incrementing a typeless variable ($n):

```
my @a = do for 1..3 {
    state $n;
    $n.^name, $n++;
}

say @a;
```

The result is "kind of" expected:

```
[(Any 0) (Int 1) (Int 2)]
```

And I say "kind of" because I've expected as the first value of $n the "undefined" value (Any).

It is like, after the first value is produced (Any) and as we increment the $n (after the first increment of $n we have a casting to an Int) there is also some time warping event in the assignment and we get also the first value to change. So we end up having the first value as 0 (zero).

Can somebody explain the exact mechanism of this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see [Any.pm6#L519](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/86a771ac0185ec3be556c92eb9e9c44c272f49bd/src/core.c/Any.pm6#L519), the candidate

```
multi sub postfix:<++>(Mu:U $a is rw) { $a = 1; 0 }
```

is used.
There are some another candidates for undefined values, you can try

```
my Bool $x; 
dd $x++; #Bool::False

my Num $y;
dd $y++; #0e0
```

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the "pushing" out to the array @a is done AFTER the action implied by the postfix ++ function?

Comment: Yes, of course. Same as for `^name`. In the array, there are returned values  of  `^name` and `++`.